# Can I easily run a vue.js webapp in a sails.js assets directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, sails.js

I am learning how to use **Sails.js** and **vue.js**. So I'm trying to develop a small app where there's a vue.js application located inside the **assets/** directory of sails.js. The idea is to serve both applications with the same server (command **sails lift**), but I'm getting some trouble to make it work.

The reason is because the sails server can serve the index file of my vue app (assets/web/dist/index.html), but other vue resources will 404, because my vue index.html file will ask for addresses like **localhost:1337/static/etc** instead of **localhost:1337/web/dist/static/etc**.

So I could make it work running **npm run-script build** in **assets/web** (my vue directory) and creating a copy of **assets/web/dist** in my assets directory. This way my vue app is served by the sails.js dev server. But I have to "compile" vue and copy it everytime I change something. It would be fine for production, but is terrible for developing.

Is there some easy way to develop this application using only one dev server, or should I split them in two apps and serve them separatelly (in dev environment) ?

I'm using sails v1.0.2 and latest bootstrap-vue (currently bootstrap ^4.0.0-beta.2 and vue ^2.5.2)

(it's available in https://github.com/lampsbr/projetao)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split it, e. g. `frontend`/`backend` directory, and it's better to have different terminal sessions for both servers because if not, it might get messy. In my [example project](https://github.com/ndabAP/vue-sails-example) with Vue.js and Sails.js, it's still possible to start both simultaneously. But that's only for very quick changes.

This is how I do it inside the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cd backend && npm run dev & cd frontend && npm run dev",
    "install": "cd frontend && npm i && cd ../backend && npm i && cd .."
},
```

You have to compile your Vue.js application only when going production and, as you mentioned, it will be pushed into `assets` directory of Sails.js. That said, only your compiled Vue.js application should be located inside your assets directory, no source files!

Another common approach is to have a `client` directory inside your Sails.js directory.